# Accessing Windows7 USB devices with C++ MinGW without installing system driver?

Tags: c++, windows, usb, mingw

I am in trouble. I have to develop a tool, which checks if an USB Stick, defined by it's hardware serial number, is connected to the computer. BUT, because the software is shipped on this USB Stick I cannot assume, that the user has installed libusb or other libraries. 
The software must not need any installation on the users computer. This is where libusb fails, because I need the libusb0.sys to access the USB devices.

In all other languages like VB, .NET C#, or Visual-C++ it is no problem, but there seems to be no easy solution for gcc and MinGW.

Or did I miss something?

Thanks

Claus

Comment: Try looking under `/cygdrive`

maybe this helps http://superuser.com/questions/532254/how-to-find-usb-devices-in-cygwin

Comment: You might need to use the Win32 API rather than libusb.

Comment: @Harry but all functions I found which are useable are part of the .net framework which ist not part of all windows systems. Also I have no idea how to access .net framework functions from gcc

Comment: You're looking at the wrong documentation, then.  Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663267%28v=vs.85%29.aspx